# Excel 2013/6 Crashes when Clicking on Second Row

Tags: microsoft-excel, freeze, crash, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

Recently I had this annoying problem with Excel 2013: in a new worksheet, if I fill in the first row and the *first cell* of the second row, the whole worksheet hangs if I then click on the *second cell*.

That's right, *click*, not even enter data. I thought updating to 2016 would have done the trick, and have tried both methods suggested [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/2013/05/07/excel-crashes-when-you-enter-data-in-a-cell/), but no.

(*If there ever was a Microsoft equivalent of "Volvo pls fix", this would be the time to use it*)

Answer (score 1):

try removing all the Office components using the removal tool
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Uninstall-Office-2013-Office-2016-or-Office-365-from-a-PC-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8

then install a fresh copy of the Office 2013 or 2016

Comment: within a week or so the problem is back again